# MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI is not showing

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I am using [MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#demo-max-picks), but the datepicker is not showing. Please help.
[image]

Here with my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI-latest/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css">
<script src="Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI-latest/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker();
});
</script>

<style>
    body { height: 400px; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<input id="mdp-demo">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [Input field usage example](http://jsfiddle.net/xbk3bwd1/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=xbk3bwd1) you have to include

- jquery.min.js (2.2.4)
- jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css
- jquery-ui.css
- jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js
- jquery-ui.min.js

### Example (copied from the link above)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="mdp-demo">
```

Comment: thank you very much! May I know how to find out from the original page?
I would like to use the below , but it doesn't work. I think i miss some src.
<div id="mdp-demo"></div>
<input type="text" id="altField" value="04/19/2017, 04/21/2017">
<!-- Dates in the 'value' attribute of the altField are automatically added to the calendar -->

Comment: **Check out the demos** on http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#demo-max-picks. If you have included all the CSS and JavaScript that is listed in my answer, it should work.

Comment: You have to change the values per jQuery, not HTML. This should help: http://jsfiddle.net/e6dawvtq/1

Answer (score 0):

You have not included style sheet link for date picker get style link from documentation hopefully it will solve your problem if not letme know

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI-latest/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css">
This is the style sheet. Am I correct?

Comment: Oh sorry I am on mobile so  didn't notice then check if the css path is correct ?