# select multiple dates using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

im trying to use the `multiDatesPicker()` to select more than one date from the same calendar. Im not popular with jQuery, so i just dont know what i have been missing.
The `datepicker()` has worked fine but once i changed it to the multiple datepicker, it has stoped to work.
here is the list the references i have alreay used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and the main code for the calendar popup is here:

```
<th>
    <div class="input-icons">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        <svg width="4" height="40" viewBox="0 0 4 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute; left: 1130px; top: 364px;">
        <line x1="2" y1="40" x2="2" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"/>
        </svg> 
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" style="height: 45px; margin-left: 7px;">
        <script>
        //initialize the calendar
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#datepicker").multiDatesPicker();
                $('.fa-calendar').click(function() {
                $("#datepicker").focus();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>  
</th>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `multiDatesPicker()` seems to be a plugin for jQuery ui. However you did not load the plugin judging from your reference list. The plugin won't work if you don't add it. If you did add it please add the error message to your question.

Comment: @MarkBaijens thats actually what i was thinking about, but honestly i didnt know how to load it, could you please tell how the <tag> would be like ?

Comment: Like every other javascript file:`<script src="https://your.web.domain.com/filename.extension"></script>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527634/multidatespicker-for-jquery-ui-is-not-showing)

Comment: @MarkBaijens Yes it did, and it's working fine! thanks